# Web2py pass a CSV-File as a Parameter for a service

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, web-services, web2py

i'm writing a webservice for web2py at the moment. I want to pass a CSV-File as a Parameter for the Webservice and read the CSV in the webservice. My problem is, when i try to pass the CSV, i get the error:

```
<class 'NameError'> name 'basestring' is not defined
Version
web2py™     Version 2.18.5-stable+timestamp.2019.04.08.04.22.03
Python  Python 3.6.8: /bin/python3 (prefix: /usr)
Traceback   

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
  File "/web2py/applications/testwebservice/controllers/default.py", line 83, in <module>
  File "/home/ff/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 421, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/web2py/applications/testwebservice/controllers/default.py", line 20, in index
    schaar = webservice.schaar(csv_reader_object)
  File "/web2py/gluon/contrib/simplejsonrpc.py", line 112, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **vars: self.call(attr, *args, **vars)
  File "/web2py/gluon/contrib/simplejsonrpc.py", line 144, in call
    self.error.get('data', None))
  File "/web2py/gluon/contrib/simplejsonrpc.py", line 38, in __init__
    if isinstance(data, basestring):
NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined
```

Heres my Code for the webservice:

```
@service.json
@service.jsonrpc
@service.jsonrpc2
def schaar(csv_reader_object):

    csvlist = csv.reader(csv_reader_object, delimiter=',')

    csv= list()
    headers = csvlist[0]

    for i,e in enumerate(csvlist):
        if i == 0:
            continue

        row_dict=dict()
        for i2, e2 in enumerate(e):
            row_dict[headers[i2]] = e2 if (e2 != None or e2 != "") else None

        csv.append(row_dict)

    return (csv)
```

Hope you can help me. I've already tried to convert the binary to string, but it failed somehow. I've already tried the `BytesIO` and `StringIO` too.

Im looking forward to your answers.

Regards Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in `gluon.contrib.simplejsonrpc`, which has since been fixed. Simply upgrade to any version of web2py after 2.18.5, and it should work (rather, you won't get that particular error anymore, though the code in question is actually in the `JSONRPCError` class, indicating some other part of your code has raised an exception).